# assortativity.nominal in igraph

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I am analysing a coauthorship network (net) of `V(net)=1327` and `E(net)=4121`.

I have tried to find the

```
assortativity.nominal(net, types=V(net)$field)
```

this is based on the *field* where the researcher belongs. I do not know why, but R crush each time I want to run this. I have run

```
assortativity(net, types=V(net)$publication)
```

that is in function of the number of publications or coautorships each researcher has, in this case there is no problem.
I just fear that the case with `assortativity.nominal` has to do with the size and order of the network.

Comment: Most likely not; assortativity is a fairly simple calculation and it should not suffer from memory issues. I'm suspecting that your `field` attribute somehow contains a value that `assortativity.nominal` doesn't like. Try converting the attribute to integers and then try again.

Comment: Thanks Támas, I have converted `field` nominal  into `field` numeric as follows: `field1 <- as.factor(V(net)$field)` and  `field2 <- as.numeric(field1)` then I have tried again `assortativity(net, types=V(net)$field2)`. However, I have the following result:  Error in `assortativity(net, types = V(net)$field2)`  
  _el argumento 2 concuerda con multiples argumentos formales _. It says that the argument does not coincide with formal arguments. The network, `net`, is an `undirected` network. I do not know if that has to do with this argument.

Comment: `assortativity` has `types1` and `types2` (which is used for directed graphs only), so using `types` will not work.

Comment: Thanks, just to be clear, not any kind of assortativity will work on `undirected` networks by using `types`. In this case it will only work, if I run `assortativity` simple. The only kind of `assortativity` that will work is `assortativity.degree(net, directed=F)`

Answer (score 7):

Something that might work:

```
assortativity_nominal(graph,as.numeric(as.factor(V(graph)$attribute)))
```

Comment: Simply converting type to a factor should work; there is no need to convert it to numeric as well: assortativity_nominal(graph,as.factor(V(graph)$attribute))

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the trait being NA for some of the vertices. If you change all the NAs to "none", then it works, however, you probably don't want this and nor do I, and I don't know how to get round it.

Comment: Is this a comment or answer?

Comment: I'm sorry it is more of a comment, but I can't comment above. It's a solution but not a very good one...

Comment: Thaks for the comment.  However, you are right, I would not like this solution.